# Offline voice recognition Kitkat

Tags: voice-command, offline, voice-recognition

Got a Moto E recently.

I was checking out the Google voice commands. It works great. But offline commands are not working. As soon as I open the voice search/Google Now offline it gives error saying not connected. I tried downloading offline language and installed the same. But still not working. Anything else am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I own a Moto X and I know that it has "two modes" of voice recognition: one activated at any time by the command "OK Google now", which appears on a black screen, and the other activated by the voice search button on search/Google now app.

Every voice command recognized on the black screen is done offline, but on the white screen it needs to reach Google to recognize the command. In this case download the offline language pack will save you some data and result in a faster command recognition, but you still need to be connected on the internet in order to do so.

Comment: How do you get the " offline language pack"?

Comment: Go to Google Settings > Search & Now > Voice > Offline speech recognition. There you can manage the downloaded languages.

Comment: What are"Google settings"?

Comment: It is an app to manage the settings of your Google account. You can reach the Google Now settings by opening Google Now, clicking on the bottom right menu and choosing the Settings option. From there just choose Voice > Offline speech recognition.

Comment: Theres no such option. Maybe i have blocked it with xprivacy